# PUT & DELETE not working for node.js mongodb project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unable to PUT or DELETE data that I have sent to MongoDB. I have tried looking for any bugs but I cannot seem to find any and do not what may be causing this error. GET and POST work fine.

I will post my controllers and views.

controllers/cards.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cardsRouter = express.Router()
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const User = require('../models/user')


// DELETE
cardsRouter.delete('/cards/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    user.cards.pull(req.params.id);
    await user.save();
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});


// UPDATE
cardsRouter.put('/cards/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const card = user.cards.id(req.params.id);
    card.overwrite(req.body);
    await user.save();
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});


// EDIT
cardsRouter.get('/:id/edit', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const card = user.cards.id(req.params.id);
    res.render('../views/cards/edit', { card });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});


// SHOW
cardsRouter.get('/cards/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const card = user.cards.id(req.params.id);
    res.render('cards/show', { card });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});



module.exports = cardsRouter
```

views/cards/edit.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include('../partials/head.ejs') %>
<body>
  <%- include('../partials/header') %>
  <h2>Edit Page</h2>

  <form action="/cards/<%= card._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Noah and The Great Flood" type="text" name="title"><br>
    <input placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOUV7mWDI34" type="text" name="link"><br>
    <input placeholder="Genesis 5:1" type="text" name="scripture"><br>
    <textarea
      placeholder="Here we can learn about how God has had mercy on humanity by giving it a second opportunity..."
      name="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes">
  </form>



</body>
</html>
```

I also have another section for posts that is doing the same exact thing.

controllers/posts.js

```
const express = require('express')
const postsRouter = express.Router()
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const Post = require('../models/post')
const User = require('../models/user')

// READ
postsRouter.get('/posts/new', auth.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('posts/new')
})

// DELETE
postsRouter.delete('/posts/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    
    if (req.user._id.equals(post.createdBy._id)) {
      await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    }
    
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});


// UPDATE
postsRouter.put('/posts/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const post = user.posts.id(req.params.id);
    post.overwrite(req.body);
    await user.save();
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});


// CREATE/POST
postsRouter.post('/posts', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.body.createdBy = req.user._id;
    const post = await Post.create(req.body);
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});


// EDIT
postsRouter.get('/posts/:id/edit', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const post = user.posts.id(req.params.id);
    res.render('posts/edit', { post });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});



// SHOW
postsRouter.get('/posts/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate('createdBy').exec();
    res.render('posts/show', { post });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});



module.exports = postsRouter
```

views/edit.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include('../partials/head') %>
<body>
  <%- include('../partials/header') %>
  <h2>Edit Page</h2>

  <form action="/posts/<%= post._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Noah and The Great Flood" type="text" name="title"><br>
    <input placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOUV7mWDI34" type="text" name="link"><br>
    <input placeholder="Genesis 5:1" type="text" name="scripture"><br>
    <textarea
      placeholder="Here we can learn about how God has had mercy on humanity by giving it a second opportunity..."
      name="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes">
  </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate. If the code blocks are too much at least point me in the direction of where to look more specifically. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the method-override package in your server?

Comment: Yes I am, it is installed and in use

Comment: Whenever I try to delete I get a 404 error if that helps